# Service down in use HERE REST APIs - Freemium Plan

Tags: here-api

I would like to know Freemium versions' SLA, because we have detected that the servers do not return any response and we way within the use free limit the following APIs: Places API, Geocoder API and Reverse Geocoder API.

In addition we are using the production server, as described in the following url: https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/dev_guide/common/request-cit-environment-rest.html, and we haven't exceeded 250k Freemium plan transactions.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you check these API again, we checked they are giving response.

Comment: Yes, we check these API and this happens very occasionally, but when it happens, it leaves us without service and after about 5 minutes it returns.

Answer (score 0):

The SLA for non-paying Freemium plan is unknown but often when service is healthy then SLA is almost the same for non-paying and paying plans.

Regarding with https://developer.here.com/faqs:

Our SLA is 99.9% monthly availability for these APIs in production:

- Maps
- Routing
- Geocoding
- Traffic
- Positioning
- Weather
- Fleet Telematics
- Search
- Transit
- HERE SDK (server components)

This SLA **comes with all our paid plans**. This **includes the Freemium plan when paying for use over 250,000 Transactions per month**, the Pro plan and some Enterprise plans.

We do not offer an SLA (Service Level Agreement) for Batch Geocoder, HERE Studio or Live Sense SDK Beta.

You can check the status of the HERE services on https://status.here.com/status

Please not forgot double check an internet connectivity of course on your side too.